# Problem join database mysql in virtual machine with express node

Tags: mysql, angular, express, ubuntu, virtualbox

I have a virtual machine on which is install ubuntu server with mysql and phpmyadmin I try to connect through express node js.
If I type `192.168.11.120/phpmyadmin` (virtual machine address in the network) on the physical machine's browser, I can access it.

After doing a `npm install mysql`, it's my code

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host     : '192.168.11.120',
user     : 'test',
password : 'test'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function(err, rows, fields) 
{
  if (err) {console.log(err)} ;

});

connection.end();
```

The console shows me the following error after doing a `"node index.js"`.

```
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.11.120:3306
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1106:14)
--------------------
at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\Boubacar\Desktop\ISTA\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
at Protocol.handshake (C:\Users\Boubacar\Desktop\ISTA\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
at Connection.connect (C:\Users\Boubacar\Desktop\ISTA\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:119:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Boubacar\Desktop\ISTA\server\index.js:8:12)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '192.168.11.120',
port: 3306,
fatal: true }
```

I can not find out if it's a problem related to virtualbox or it's the code that is not good

Comment: have you checked if the Port 3306 is open? Check the firrewall of your virtuell maschine

Comment: how do we check if the port is open?

Comment: for example nmap is available on all Operating system. check your search engine for alternativs